# Windows 7 backup to network location out of space

Tags: backup, windows-7

I've got a domain of 10-15 Windows 7 computers that I don't have physical access to. They are using Windows Backup to only backup certain files (Desktop, Fav's, PST, things like that). The problem I'm having is that my server is running out of room. How can I set the backup to use, say, only 20gb, or to delete backups older than one month?

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file with the following command line:

**forfiles -p "C:\path\path" -s -m *.* -d  -c "cmd /c del @path"**

Schedule that file to be ran on a daily basis.

Comment: You'll also need to download Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)

Comment: You can also get forfiles by going to (ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/ResKit/y2kfix/x86/)

Comment: And make sure you place it in System32 folder under Windows